# webpackdevserver --inline & hot , working with npm script but not in code

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

If I launch webackdevserver with npm scripts it work:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "set NODE_ENV=dev && node server/server.js",
    "inline": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.dev.conf.js",
  }
```

This works fine:

```
npm run inline
```

But npm run dev doesn't work.

In server/server.js I launch it like this:

```
    var compiler = webpack(conf);
    var server  = new WebpackDevServer(compiler);
    server.listen(8081, "localhost");
```

What is weird is that webpackdevserver is not served to the client and I don't know why. 
[image]

[image]

Config is the same, any idea why in one case it's not serving webpackdevserver and reload/hot doesn't work ?

The only thing I add for the second version is inline and progress :

```
 devServer: {
    clientLogLevel: 'warning',
    historyApiFallback: true,
    hot: true,
    compress: true,
    host: HOST || config.dev.host,
    port: PORT || config.dev.port,
    open: config.dev.autoOpenBrowser,
    overlay: config.dev.errorOverlay
      ? { warnings: false, errors: true }
      : false,
    publicPath: config.dev.assetsPublicPath,
    proxy: config.dev.proxyTable,
    quiet: true, // necessary for FriendlyErrorsPlugin
    watchOptions: {
      poll: config.dev.poll,
    },
    inline: true,
    progress: true
  },
```